# What does it mean by letter 'g' in a kernel version string such as 3.4.0-gd59db4e?

Tags: linux, kernel

In my Nexus 5 device, I can see the kernel version as follows:

**3.4.0-gd59db4e**

I know **3.4.0** is the linux kernel version number, and **d59db4e** is short of a commit **sha1**. [here is another example.](http://marcin.jabrzyk.eu/posts/2014/05/building-and-booting-nexus-5-kernel)

I just wonder: What does it mean by letter 'g'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It stands for *git*, the name of the version control system used for the Linux kernel. Git itself isn't an abbreviation, it's just the name of the system. The `git describe` command is what's used to generate these version identifiers, and its manpage describes the format:

> The hash suffix is "-g" + 7-char
>          abbreviation for the tip commit of parent ... The "g" prefix stands for "git" and is
>          used to allow describing the version of a software depending on the SCM the
>          software is managed with. This is useful in an environment where people may use
>          different SCMs.